# Combining two NVIDIA video cards to drive three monitors in cloned mode

Tags: windows-xp, nvidia-graphics-card

Subject: Combining two NVIDIA video cards to drive three monitors in cloned mode (each 1080p monitor is in a separate room). NVIDIA universal driver version 301.42, EVGA X58 Motherboard (two PCI-E slots), Windows XP Professional.

If I understand some forum discussions correctly, it's possible to combine two different video cards (non-SLI configuration) to drive three cloned/mirrored monitors. But when I combine a GTX 560 LE and a GeForce 9500 GT, and select cloning mode in NVIDIA Control Panel, the monitors do not clone, but display in extended mode ('horizontal desktop' or 'horizontal span'). The screens divide, with two monitors displaying the right side of the extended desktop, while a third monitor displays the left side of the extended desktop.

I need the same output to all three monitors.

Answer (score 3):

You are doing this wrong. Cloning a monitor can be done with a VGA Y Split Cable (M/F). These guys cost ~$5 and will prevent any headache and power consumption problems associated with running 2 GPUs.

In fact, I once made one with the Cat5 wires (ethernet) by simply extending the VGA pins in a Y fashion.